# Does Pakistan harbor terrorists?

Tags: politics, terrorism

In wake of the recent killing of OBL, Pakistan has been accused of supporting and harboring terrorists. Neighboring old-time foe India has long accused Pakistan of using terrorism as an instrument of state policy. Pakistan obviously denies all the accusations.

So my question is that is there any definite evidence to prove that Pakistan is a terrorist country?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what constitutes "definite evidence".

Comment: Define what you mean by "terrorist country"? Yes, by some definitions terrorists are present in Pakistan. But so are they present in the US also. A better phrasing would be whether Pakistan sponsors terrorism.

Answer (score 26):

The answer is a resounding yes. Pakistan began sponsoring anti-India terrorists around the late 1980's and early 1990's (to ferment unrest in Kashmir because it lost conventional wars), and several former Pakistani Prime Ministers and Presidents have publicly accepted this fact. Of course, they were usually referred to as "freedom fighters" etc.

See the section called "Admission of state sponsored terrorism by Pakistani authorities" at [this link](http://forums.bharat-rakshak.com/viewtopic.php?t=5923&p=1086201) for further references. Some quotes from referenced links:

[SPIEGEL Interview with Pervez Musharraf](http://www.spiegel.de/international/world/0,1518,721110,00.html)

> SPIEGEL: Why did you form militant
>   underground groups to fight India in
>   Kashmir?
>
> Musharraf: They were indeed formed.
>   The government turned a blind eye
>   because they wanted India to discuss
>   Kashmir.
>
> SPIEGEL: It was the Pakistani security
>   forces that trained them.
>
> Musharraf: The West was ignoring the
>   resolution of the Kashmir issue, which
>   is the core issue of Pakistan. We
>   expected the West -- especially the
>   United States and important countries
>   like Germany -- to resolve the Kashmir
>   issue. Has Germany done that?
>
> SPIEGEL: Does that give Pakistan the
>   right to train underground fighters?
>
> Musharraf: Yes, it is the right of any
>   country to promote its own interests
>   when India is not prepared to discuss
>   Kashmir at the United Nations and is
>   not prepared to resolve the dispute in
>   a peaceful manner.

Also, from the same interview in 2010, allegations of continued training of terrorists in Pakistan.

> SPIEGEL: A German member of the
>   militant Islamic Movement of
>   Uzbekistan, 36-year-old Ahmad Sidiqi,
>   who has been held by US forces in
>   Afghanistan since July, allegedly told
>   his American interrogators that he was
>   trained in Pakistan and confessed
>   there were plans to attack Europe.
>   Why, nine years after 9/11, does
>   Pakistan remain a breeding ground for
>   international terrorism?
>
> Musharraf: We poisoned Pakistani civil
>   society for 10 years when we fought
>   the Soviets in Afghanistan in the
>   1980s. It was jihad and we brought in
>   militants from all over the world,
>   with the West and Pakistan together in
>   the lead role. After the withdrawal of
>   the Soviet troops, the West left
>   Pakistan with 25,000 mujahedeen and
>   al-Qaida fighters, without any plan
>   for rehabilitation or resettlement.
>   While you were mostly concerned with
>   the reunification of Germany, we had
>   to cope with this. Now you expect
>   Pakistan to pull out a magic wand and
>   make all of this suddenly disappear?
>   That is not doable -- this will take
>   time.

From [The Hindu](http://www.hinduonnet.com/holnus/000200907081441.htm), July 2009

> Islamabad (PTI): For the first time,
>   Pakistan President Asif Ali Zardari
>   admitted that militants and extremists
>   were "created and nurtured" in the
>   country as a policy to achieve some
>   short-term tactical objectives.

Also, some confessions from Guanatanamo Bay detainees regarding ISI (Pakistan's primary intelligence and covert organization) support provided to terrorists, [according to Wikileaks](http://www.hindustantimes.com/rssfeed/Americas/ISI-allowed-terrorists-to-attack-India-says-WikiLeaks/Article1-695219.aspx). From the introduction:

> The ISI facilitated militants to cross
>   the border to carry out strikes on
>   Indian targets chosen by the Pakistan
>   Army, several detainees at the
>   Guantanamo Bay facility told US
>   interrogators, according to a fresh
>   set of American diplomatic cables
>   released by WikiLeaks.

The [Pakistani army was also implicated](http://www.indianexpress.com/news/kasab-trial-pak-army-sponsored-the-26-11-a/588765/) (though not conclusively proved) to be involved in the Mumbai 2008 terrorist attacks, where all the participating terrorists had been given "commando training".

> "Kasab in his confession has said one
>   Major General was present during their
>   training and supervised the firing
>   practice. The name of this Major
>   General was deliberately not revealed
>   to the attackers as he occupies a
>   senior position in the army," Nikam
>   said.

The support continues even now, but due to changing factors, the terrorists they support have now come into the global limelight(due to links with Al-Qaeda of course).

Since terrorists receive support from the army, democratically-elected or coup-instated government heads and intelligence agencies, it would be fair to say that Pakistan is a state sponsoring terrorism.

Comment: @Sklivvz I can see many links e.g. http://www.spiegel.de/international/world/0,1518,721110,00.html , http://www.time.com/time/asia/magazine/2001/0205/kashmir_sb1.html etc. But again I may be biased. :)

Comment: @may And where exactly do they say that there is state-sponsored terrorism in Pakistan?

Comment: @apo: there's no need to answer in comments. Fix your answer instead with the same information.

Comment: "SPIEGEL: Why did you form militant underground groups to fight India in Kashmir?

Musharraf: They were indeed formed. The government turned a blind eye because they wanted India to discuss Kashmir.
SPIEGEL: It was the Pakistani security forces that trained them.

Musharraf: The West was ignoring the resolution of the Kashmir issue, which is the core issue of Pakistan. We expected the West -- especially the United States and important countries like Germany -- to resolve the Kashmir issue. Has Germany done that?" **One country's terrorist is another's freedom fighter!**

Comment: I agree the Spiegel is a good reference for the past, but not for the present: "Why, nine years after 9/11, does Pakistan remain a breeding ground for international terrorism?" "We poisoned Pakistani civil society [...] when we fought the Soviets in Afghanistan in the 1980s. [..] we brought in militants from all over the world, with the West and Pakistan together in the lead role.[...] the West left Pakistan with 25,000 mujahedeen and al-Qaida fighters,[...] Now you expect Pakistan to pull out a magic wand and make all of this suddenly disappear? That is not doable -- this will take time."

Comment: No Pakistan is definitely not a terrorist state. Pakistan has fought terrorism on her own soil for so long and has lost tens of thousands of her children in that war. Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_in_Pakistan) to see how much Pakistan has suffered and how involved she is in the war against terror. As for the links provided by @apoorv020, those are quotes from newspapers (The Hindu, really?) whose neutrality is disputed. I can provide hundreds of links from Pakistan's newspapers which will refute the point. As for Kashmir, it is a disputed territory and lots of bl

Comment: @user2516:a)If Zardari says something, it does not matter whether it's printed in the dawn or the Hindu(the Hindu is one of the most respected papers in India btw). b) As for Kashmir, LeT is on the UN's, US's and India's terrorist list. Disputed territory or not, objectively Pakistan state mechanism supports terrorism. c) The Pakisatani govt is distinct from Pakistani populace, as is true for any nation. But, over 20 years of regimes have maintained the same policy on terrorism, so it's acceptable in my view to call the Pakistani govt a sponsor of terrorism.

Comment: -1 A: None of your citations indicate Pakistan harboured terrorists. B: Your sources are mainly opinions of people not evidence. I wonder why no action was taken by mods against the OP. Sklivvz, are you Indian?